# Start a NSTimer when view loads

Tags: swift, nstimer, viewdidload

I have want to make a simple clock app where the colon blinks to make it look better. My code so far is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var clockLabel: UILabel!
var timerRunning = true
var timer = NSTimer()
var OnOff = 0
var colon = ":"
var hour = 0
var minute = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    clockLabel.text = ("\(hour)\(colon)\(minute)")
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "Counting", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func Counting(){ 
    if OnOff == 1 {
    OnOff = 0
    colon = ":"
    clockLabel.text = ("\(hour)\(colon)\(minute)")
    }
    if OnOff == 0 {
    OnOff = 1
    colon = ""
    clockLabel.text = ("\(hour)\(colon)\(minute)")
    }
}
```

The way I would like this to work is that the timer starts at exactly that moment when the view loads. I don't want to have to press a button to make the colon start blinking. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's not working exactly ? Currently it seems the timer fires when the view loads and repeats every second thereafter... Your code looks fine to me...

Comment: You seem to be turning the colon off immediately after turning it on without a pause for displaying.  How frequently do you want it to turn on and off?

Comment: The "clock" part is missing. Where do you set `hour` and `minute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with your timer (Your question title suggests otherwise), as far as I can tell it should fire every second after the view loads.

One thing I did notice is an issue in your code execution path:
The two consequent if statements overlap if you change the variable (in the first one), so read on to see my solution.

A little improvement I would make -- as the `OnOff` variable seems to be binary in nature -- let's make that a boolean type:

```
var colonShown : Bool = false // this is your "OnOff" variable (changed it to be more clear to the reader + made it boolean (you treat it as a boolean, so why not make it boolean?))
```

And then, in your timing function (I renamed it to `tick()`):

```
// renamed your Counting() function, no particular reason for that (sorry if that causes confusion) -- you can replace your Counting() function with this one (also make sure to update your timer selector that references the "Counting()" function on each "tick")
func tick(){ 
    colonShown = !colonShown // toggle boolean value
    colon = colonShown ? ":" : "" // neat one-liner for your if statement

    clockLabel.text = ("\(hour)\(colon)\(minute)")

}
```

Comment: This solution is way more [readable](http://importblogkit.com/2015/03/writing-readable-code/).  Excellent.

Comment: @nhgrif Thanks for your input, appreciate it.

Comment: @EliaDöhler Glad ot helped. Feel free to accept this answer (mark the tick underneath the votes) if it was helpful. Good luck with your project!